# Add a parameter to a dynamic function

Tags: javascript

I have a generic javascript class that creates an html input element.  The code allows me to pass a function as a string that will be called whenever the value of the element changes, using jQuery's change method.  I'm using the following code:

```
1.  var changeFunction = "runThisCode()";
2.  
3.  var elem = $("<input/>").attr(id: someID, type: "text", size: 20);
4.  elem.change(function () {
5.     var fn = new Function(changeFunction);
6.     fn();
7.  });
```

I'd like to pass the id of the element in the change function. Is there a way for me to add a parameter at either on line 5 or 6?

Comment: If you're going to do evil, you might as well use `eval` directly. Why do you want to use a string for your function call ?

Comment: I have a configuration file used with my code. In the actual code, line one doesn't actually exist.  It's passed as a parameter to the object constructor.

Comment: Do you know you may call a global function whose name you have using `window[functionname]()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide arguments name in `Function` which will be available in created function body. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXAf7/)

```
1.  var changeFunction = "runThisCode(id)";
2.  
3.  var elem = $("<input/>").attr(id: someID, type: "text", size: 20);
4.  elem.change(function () {
5.     var fn = new Function("id", changeFunction);
6.     fn(someID);
7.  });
```

Comment: Because you keep using implicit eval when there are way better ways available.

Comment: How do you know his requirement? there might be some condition he has to use eval.

Comment: I cannot think of a single requirement that requires `eval`. Not a single.

Comment: Sushil, this isn't working for me. I get an error about id being undefined.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine  How different JavaScript templating framework works?

Comment: @Sushil They tokenize and run the tokens.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine is it possible without eval?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I have never used tokenizer, can you show me some docs. or you can share some code

Comment: Sorry, Sushil. This actually worked. I was applying it to the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

```
var changeFunction = runThisCode;

var elem = $("<input/>").attr(id: someID, type: "text", size: 20);
elem.change(function () {
    changeFunction(this.id);
});
```

Really. There is no need to use strings to store functions in variables. This is bad, and the solution I just showed you works fine.

Actually, you can just do the following if the code is really in the order shown:

```
var elem = $("<input/>").attr(id: someID, type: "text", size: 20);
elem.change(runThisCode);

function runThisCode() {
    // 'this.id' gives you the ID.
    // And so does 'someID'.
}
```

Comment: This isn't an option at this time. The way the code is set up, I really do need the string converted to a string.

Comment: @Robbert Is it because `runThisCode` is only available in the change event?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply this ?

```
var changeFunction = "runThisCode";
var elem = $("<input/>").attr(id: someID, type: "text", size: 20);
elem.change(function () { window[changeFunction](this.id) });
```

If you can't have your changeFunction directly like this, you may do

```
var changeFunction = changeFunction.slice(0, -2);
```

to remove the parenthesis.